# The process cannot access the file,it is being used by another process in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting this error
  " System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wmo\Content\UploadFolder\Ad-2015 .xlsx' because it is being used by another process."  when am executing my code. i developed my application using mvc and c# is using language.i put my published files in IIS wwwroot folder.
 my code is

```
public ActionResult ImportData(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {if (file != null)
        {
            if (Request.Files["file"].ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["file"].FileName);

                if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadFolder/") + Request.Files["file"].FileName;
                    loc = fileLocation;
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);

                    }
                    Request.Files["file"].SaveAs(fileLocation); }}}}
```

I have getting the error from this line "System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);"

Comment: Make sure this file is not open in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

The web site likely has it open in a process that is not disposed. Check any code that references the file prior to this point that is IDisposable and wrap it in a using statement. If not disposed, it will hold the file open and you can't delete it.

Answer (score -3):

Are you using FileStream instance without importing `System.IO` via a using statement?

here is my code and it's working as expected.

`using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
   model.PhotoPath.CopyTo(fileStream);
}`

Comment: Downvoted because he would have a compilation error if this were the case, whereas OPs description is that of a runtime error. It's not a question as to whether the code is right or wrong as that won't matter, the file has a lock and the application is unable to open it.